# Inherited classes won't write to file

Tags: c++, inheritance, stream

So, I'm having a problem with my inherited classes writing items to a file. I'll post a sample of the code because there are multiple instances of it and it won't write these certain items to a file. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, it's writing everything in the parent class just fine to a file, but those things from a child class won't write. This part has already been done in each child class:

```
//Parameterized constructor signature
Hourly::Hourly(int e, string n, string a, string p, double w, double h) :MyEmployee(e, n, a, p)
```

Here's the driver without the headers.

```
string fileInput;
    string employCategory = "";
    const string HOURLY = "Hourly";
    const string SALARIED = "Salaried";
    int answer;
    int count = 0;
    const int ONE = 1;
    const int TWO = 2;
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 4;
    MyEmployee* payroll[ARRAY_SIZE];
    ifstream myOpenFile;
    ofstream myWrittenFile;
    payroll[0] = new Hourly(1, "H. Potter", "Privet Drive", "201-9090", 40, 12.00);
    payroll[1] = new Hourly(3, "R. Weasley", "The Burrow", "892-2000", 40, 10.00);
    payroll[2] = new Salaried(2, "A. Dumbledore", "Hogwarts", "803-1230", 1200);
    payroll[3] = new Salaried(4, "R. Hagrid", "Hogwarts", "910-8765", 1000);
    cout << "This program has two options:\n1 - Create a data file\n2 - Read data from a file and print paychecks.";
    //This loop will test if the user's input is valid.
    do
    {
        //Here, the user will enter a value to be used to either print checks or write a file.
        cout << "\nPlease enter <1> to create a file or <2> to print checks: ";
        cin >> answer;
        //The user entered one, so we'll write a file.
        if (answer == ONE)
        {
            cin.sync();
            cin.clear();
            cout << "\nPlease enter in the name of the file you wish to write to. Please don't forget to add .txt to the end: ";
            getline(cin, fileInput);
            myWrittenFile.open(fileInput);
            for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
            {
                MyEmployee* empPtr = payroll[i];
                if (typeid(*empPtr) == typeid(Hourly))
                {
                    Hourly* empHPtr = static_cast<Hourly*>(empPtr);
                }
                else if (typeid(*empPtr) == typeid(Salaried))
                {
                    Salaried* empSPtr = static_cast<Salaried*>(empPtr);
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
            {
                payroll[i]->writeData(myWrittenFile);
            }
            myWrittenFile.close();
            cout << "\nData saved .....";
            for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
            {
                delete payroll[i];
                payroll[i] = NULL;
            }


}
```

Here's a part from the parent class which includes writing to a file:

```
void MyEmployee::writeData(ofstream& out)
{
    out << empNum << "\n";
    out << name << "\n";
    out << address << "\n";
    out << phoneNum << "\n";
}
```

Here's a part of the child class:

```
void Hourly::writeData(ofstream& out)
{
    out << hoursWorked << "\n";
    out << wage << "\n";
    MyEmployee::writeData(out);
}
```

Comment: Without knowing exactly about your class declarations it's a bit hard to tell, but did you declare the `writeData(ofstream& out)` member functions using `virtual` properly?

Comment: Why are you using dynamic memory for `payroll`?  This is not Java or C#.  Only use dynamic memory when you can justify it.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The justification is to utilize polymorphism (which must be done by reference or pointer) and avoid object slicing, since storing just `MyEmployee` would unwittingly clip extended class content during assignment. While I concur the OP would be better off using `std::unique_ptr< MyEmployee>` for the memory elements, dynamic management of *some* form is, none the less, required for what is being tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems, it is because your `writeData()` function is not declared as virtual.

When a function is declared as virtual and was overriden in the derived classes, it will be computed in the runtime what the function must be exactly called. ([Virtual method tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)).

Your function is not declared as virtual, so calling it from the `MyEmployee` pointer, you call the `writeData()` function which was defined in `MyEmployee` class, not in its derived classes. This is why it doesn't write to the file any data from the derived class.

PS:

```
typeid(*empPtr) == typeid(Hourly)
typeid(*empPtr) == typeid(Salaried)
```

These expressions will be always `false`.

Comment: No way...this is the way the teacher told us. What would work best?

Comment: @nelson2013 is your question about virtual functions, or `typeid`?